# How to log out a locked down user remotely

Tags: shortcut-keys, teamviewer, kiosk

I've set up a load of kiosks to run in a custom desktop environment - I've added the code below.
I need to remotely control the kiosks using TeamViewer, and I need to be able to log them in and out. What's the easiest way to do this remotely?

CTRL+ALT+F1 doesn't work (@Jos pointed this out below which is why my question has changed).
I've tried pressing CTRL+AlT+T to open a terminal window, but this doesn't seem to work.
CTRL+ALT+Delete isn't working either.

```
#!bin/bash
# starting xscreensaver
xscreensaver -nosplash & while true;
do
    teamviewer
    firefox
    sleep5s;
done
```

Comment: The Teamviewer server running on the Ubuntu desktop will not serve the consoles 1-6 because it is running (via lightdm or gdm) on console 7. If you must issue a command, fire up a terminal process or ssh into the desktop.

Comment: @Jos Thank you for your quick reply! I'm actually running a custom desktop environment so I'll update my question quickly to reflect this

Comment: Hmmm I would open a terminal and kill the session? (`sudo pkill -u {username}`) That is: I assume you can get to an admin(?) If not... the cogwheel top right is that present?

Comment: Another: command line `gnome-session-quit` should prompt the logout dialog.

Comment: @Rinzwind It's locked down to the point that other windows cannot be opened, and the cogwheen (that entire bar actually) isn't present. Adding terminal to the list of programs in my desktop environment doesn't seem to solve anything - the only way I seem to be able to get to terminal is ctrl+alt+f1 which isn't possible through teamviewer. :(

Comment: Then you have a problem that might not have a sollution... you will need ssh or at least a terminal :(

Comment: @Rinzwind That's a huge pain. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Launching SSH at boot (alongside firefox and teamviewer) then running the command

```
sudo pkill -KILL -u user
```

returned to login screen, to which I can connect teamviewer and continue use.